# Exit from fish shell

Tags: command-line, bash, fish

I have Fish setup as my default shell. I want to exit from `fish` to `bash`.

How can I do that with opened fish shell?

Comment: Why just don't run `bash` command ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just type `bash` and you'll start the **bash** shell. type `exit` to return to **fish** shell when you're done.

Comment: `bash --login` worked for me.